# Posting to API With Curl in Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl, cmd

I'm trying to create batch file that grabs individual files in a directory and posts them to a ticket-creating API. I have a working `.bat` file, but I get:

```
"Couldn't read data from file text.txt, this makes an empty post".
```

Here is the `.bat` file I'm working with right now.

```vb
@echo off 
set localdir=C:\Users\me\Desktop\SmallBatchTest

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%x in ('dir /B/D %localdir%') do (
  set FILENAME=%localdir%\%%x
  curl -u xxxxx:X -H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
      -X POST --data-binary @%%x "http://myurl"
)
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

Try to expand to the filepath with `~f` `FOR /?` because `%%x` show only relative path of `%localdir%` so if your script are not in that dir, curl will not find the file.

see:

```vb
@echo off
setlocal
set "localdir=C:\Users\me\Desktop\SmallBatchTest"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%x in ('dir /B/D %localdir%') do (
  set FILENAME=%%~fx
  echo curl -u xxxxx:X ^
         -H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
         -X POST --data-binary ^
         @%%~fx "http://myurl"
  echo FILENAME: '!FILENAME!'
)
```

Comment: But his code is setting filename to `%localdir%\%%x`, which indicates _exactly_ where the file is located...

Comment: @SomethingDark the OP was not using `%filename%` in `curl` comand anyway

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, because when I enter the information like this, the output (@%%~fx) becomes "C:\Users\me\myfile.txt". It does not go all the way to the folder with the files that I need to upload. Am I missing something obvious? It looks like it is reading files from the correct directors (that is \Desktop\SmallBatchTest), but the curl thinks that those files are in C:\Users\me instead. I managed to upload the files by putting copies in both directories, but that is obviously not ideal. Now I KNOW that I'm missing something simple.

Comment: @grandhighpoobah Please edit your question with more information because I can't read in the mind. I suggest you using the command `tree` to show us the files you want to send, and those you do not want. Then you may need to write a search mask.